# How can I disable button in backoffice when make action with another button - HYBRIS?

Tags: java, xml, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi experts how can I disable button action in backoffice when make action with another button?

For example when I create order from storefront then in backoffice in orders tab for current order i have 2 action button. APROVE and REJECT.

[image]

When approve order I still see Reject button. How can disable this button after approve?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your action class ( which implements `CockpitAction`), you have to override `canPerform` method to return true/false based on your business logic.

For instance, you can refer to how Customer's Enable/Disable action works OOTB.

In `b2bcommercebackoffice-backoffice-config.xml` you can find

```
<context merge-by="module" type="B2BCustomer" component="editorareaactions">
    <y:actions xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
        <y:group qualifier="common">
            <y:label>actiongroup.common</y:label>               
            <y:action action-id="de.hybris.platform.b2bcommerce.backoffice.actions.disableb2bcustomeraction" property="currentObject"/>
            <y:action action-id="de.hybris.platform.b2bcommerce.backoffice.actions.enableb2bcustomeraction" property="currentObject"/>
        </y:group>
    </y:actions>
</context>
```

Now refer to **disableb2bcustomeraction** or **enableb2bcustomeraction** class how they have implemented **canPerform** method.

e.g.

```
public boolean canPerform(ActionContext<B2BCustomerModel> ctx) {
    Object data = ctx.getData();
    if (data != null && data instanceof B2BCustomerModel) {
        B2BCustomerModel b2bCustomerModel = (B2BCustomerModel) data;
        UserModel currentUser = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
        boolean isActive = b2bCustomerModel.getActive();
        boolean isUserMemberOfAdminGroup = this.userService.isMemberOfGroup(currentUser,
                this.userService.getAdminUserGroup());
        boolean isUserMemberOfB2BAdminGroup = this.userService.isMemberOfGroup(currentUser,
                this.userService.getUserGroupForUID("b2badmingroup"));
        return (isUserMemberOfAdminGroup || isUserMemberOfB2BAdminGroup) && isActive;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```